# How to mask when you are using a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, mask

I have a list of unique names (4,300 to be exact). **unique_names = ['James', 'Erika', 'Akshay', 'Neil', etc..].** 
I have a column in a dataframe, where every row has it's own list of names. 
I have to find out which rows in this column contain a name from my unique_names list.

I have tried masking, but every time it only gives back 2 rows rather than all the rows that contain a name from my list unique_names.

```
for name in unique_names: 
    if name in unique_names: 
       mask = df['names'].apply(lambda x: name in x) 
       df1 = df[mask]
```

My expected result is for every single row that contains a unique name from my list unique_names, instead I only get a return of two rows that contain the name 'Akshay' in the list of names, although I see other rows contain names like 'Neil' and 'Erika' those are not returned.

Comment: `df['names'].isin(unique_names)`

Comment: that only gives a few values, not all the rows that contain a value from unique_names

Comment: You're overwriting `df1` every time you find a matching name, so it will only contain the last one.

Comment: @muchappreciated did you actually try it?

Comment: is there a way to prevent it from overwriting the last value? @barmar

Comment: @ballpointben yes, it only gave back a result of 68 matches when there are many more

Comment: Append to the dataframe instead of assigning to the dataframe.

Comment: @muchappreciated I don’t know what to tell you, that will produce the correct mask. You must have copied it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would rethink how you are doing this problem. First things first your original code iterates over names from a container called unique_names, then subsequently checks for if it is in unique_names. Every single iteration will pass that test because you pull them from the same container you test for membership of.

My best advice would be to iterate over the rows rather than names. Pseudocode would be as follows:

```py
rows_with_unique = list()
for row in dataframe:
    for name in unique_names:
        if name in row:
          rows_with_unique.append(row) (or whatever you are trying to extract)
```

Comment: This will return when it finds the first matching row, it won't return all of them. You could make it a generator and use `yield` instead of `return`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the catch! Just dumped it into a container :)

Comment: when I try this it brings back the whole contents of the row, is there a way to just bring in the index / or bring back all the relevant rows in a dataframe?

Comment: @muchappreciated Sorry for taking a while to get back, there is a way. If this is a python array, you need only to add: 'row.index(name)'. This will place into the container the index at which the name is located.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. Could you explain further how to return the rows that contain a unique_name in it as a new dataframe? ideally, I would want to return if every row that includes a unique_name along with the index it is associated with or ID (id is a column that I have in the dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the following would suffice.

```
mask = df['names'].apply(lambda x: any(name in x for name in unique_names))
```

If `unique_names` is a `set` and the number of names per row is small:

```
mask = df['names'].apply(lambda x: any(name in unique_names for name in x))
```

Or:

```
mask = df['names'].apply(lambda x: not unique_names.isdisjoint(x)))
```